# Strange error with simple VBA function

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following function:

```
Sub numbers2()

    barrier1 = Sheets("screen_3_TE_NONSCLIENT").Cells(8, 5)
    MsgBox (barrier1)

End sub
```

When I try to run it I get the following error however (translated from Dutch).

```
Error 13: types do not match
```

Any thoughts what goes wrong here?

Comment: try drop the bracket for msgbox. use `Msgbox barrier1`

Comment: Is there an error value in that cell?

Comment: Is it a merged cell?

Comment: @Rosetta having those brackets is perfectly acceptable. It shouldn't  be a problem.

Comment: @litelite, oops... you are right... and Rory is most right... I recreated the error 13 by putting the cell with an error value. Merged cell works fine.

Comment: you really should define barrier1 before using it... otherwise this sort of error will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Rory suggested rightly, it could be due to error value in the cell such as `#N/A`.

To handle error value in cells, try convert them to string

```
msgbox (Cstr(barrier1))
```

You will receive the error in text message such as below for `#N/A` error.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

barrier1 is a Range object, you should use:

MsgBox (barrier1.Value)

Comment: Actually, it isn't because there is no `Set` keyword.

Comment: `barrier` doesn't appear to be a range object -- unless it's declared elsewhere, it's a `Variant` type.

Comment: @DavidZemens `Variant` always have an underlying type, the variable will be treated as a variable of that type during runtime. avb suggest that that underlying type might be `Range`  (which is not true, it will be somtething like `integer` or `string` )

Comment: @litelite yes I'm well aware of this all, my point remains though that `barrier1` isn't a Range object, and there's nothing in the OP's code which would suggest otherwise. Yes, a Variant type *can* be assigned a Range object, but this would require a valid object assigment statement using the `Set` keyword (which Rory already mentioned above)